# How to change the language of the date (day of week) in Yosemite's lock screen?

Tags: macos, language

When my iMac enters the lock screen, my default language for the buttons is German; but the language of the day of week displayed in the upper right corner is English. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: I assume the rest of the OS is displaying German text, yes?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Try un-checking the Date options (Show the day...|Show date) in System Preferences > Date & Time > Clock tab. Then close System Preferences, go back and re-check the two options.

Comment: Cool, that worked. You could post an answer so I can mark the answer as solution and upvote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck the Date options in `System Preferences > Date & Time > Clock` tab.

[image]

Then close and reopen System Preferences, and re-check the two options.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [this article](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18435?locale=en_US) from Apple's website.

> **OS X Yosemite: Customize formats to display dates, times, and more**
>
> Change the language and formats used to display dates, times, numbers,
>   and currencies in Finder windows and apps, such as Mail. For example,
>   if the region for your Mac is set to United States, but the format
>   language is set to French, then dates in Finder windows and email
>   messages appear in French.
>
> Tip:   If you just want to change how time is shown in the menu bar,
>   select the “Time format” checkbox in the Language & Region preference
>   pane, or select the 24-hour option in the Clock pane of Date & Time
>   preferences. To show the date in the menu bar, also select “Show Date”
>   in the Clock pane.
>
> 1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Language & Region.
> 2. Choose a geographic region from the Region pop-up menu, to use the region’s date, time, number, and currency formats.
> 3. To customize the formats or change the language used to display them, click Advanced, then set options.
>
>    In the General pane, you can choose the language to use for showing
>      dates, times, and numbers, and set formats for numbers, currency, and
>      measurements.
>
>    In the Dates and Times panes, you can type in the Short, Medium, Long,
>      and Full fields, and rearrange or delete elements. You can also drag
>      new elements, such as Quarter or Milliseconds, into the fields. If
>      you’re not using a 24-hour clock, you can replace AM and PM with
>      whatever you type in those fields.
> 4. When you’re done customizing formats, click OK.
>
>    The region name in Language & Region preferences now includes “Custom”
>      to indicate that you customized formats.
>
>    Your formats are visible in Finder windows and in some apps. For
>      example, dates in Mail or Notes show your custom format.
>
> To undo all of your changes for a region, choose the region again from
>   the Region pop-up menu. To undo just your changes to advanced options,
>   click Advanced, click the pane where you want to undo your changes,
>   then click Restore Defaults.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help, because my language and region settings all match German. And all displayed dates, times and so on in applications show the correct format - except the one displayed on the lock screen.

Comment: @mortomanos This thread from the Apple community is old but could you check if the post by Jurek Zakrecki works: [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3300685)